# How to building JSON result C#,MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this data

[image: data]

and want to return it like

[image: json]

I wrote this code

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTime()
{
    var data = _db.CourseTimes.Select(c => new { c.Day, c.StartTime, c.EndTime })
        .GroupBy(c=>c.Day).ToList();

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is the JSON you are getting back currently? What exactly do you want to change? Can you be more specific in your question

Comment: Avoid adding code/data as images (unless it is indeed a question about image processing).

Comment: thanks for comment .
I would custom JSON result
her to be like this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCbHl.png

Comment: maybe you can use:     var DataJs = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTime()
{
     var data = _db.CourseTimes
         .GroupBy(c => c.Day)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, v => v.Select(c => new { start = c.StartTime, stop = c.EndTime }));

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Group by the day and use a dictionary with day as key to get the expected format you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to transform your data into a class that only has the Start and Stop properties; you might also have to call `.ToDictionary` in order to let the JSON Converter know what you really want:

```
// Class for Database input
public class Course {
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

// Class for JSON output
public class StartEnd {
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
}

// Some data to test :)
var testData = new[] {
    new Course() {
        Day = "Sunday",
        StartTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 08:20:00"),
        EndTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 10:20:00")
    },
    new Course() {
        Day = "Saturday",
        StartTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 11:00:00"),
        EndTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 14:00:00")
    },
    new Course() {
        Day = "Monday",
        StartTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 18:20:00"),
        EndTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 21:20:00")
    },
    new Course() {
        Day = "Saturday",
        StartTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 20:00:00"),
        EndTime = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000 22:00:00")
    },
};

// The actual data processing
var jsonData = testData
    .GroupBy(x => x.Day, x => new StartEnd() { Start = x.StartTime, Stop = x.EndTime })     // Convert to output type while grouping
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());                                            // Convert to dictionary, iterating IEnumerables creates by GroupBy
```